# using puelocesar / android-lib-magick

Tags: android, imagemagick

I am  a beginner in Android. I want a sample app which uses this library: https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick. I tried to use https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick before - I made lots of changes to make it work but the result I got was not satisfactory.

I just want to know which class to call for a particular thing.

These are the effects i am getting using https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick

[image: with no effect]
[image: Uniform Noise]
[image: Poisson Noise]
[image: Multiplicative Noise]
[image: Laplacian Noise]
[image: Impulse Noise]
[image: Gausian Noise]
[image: Blur]
[image: Charcoal]
[image: Edge]

blur, charcoal and no effect looks exactly same. when i select edge it shows blur image.
and the noise effects appear but they look like red and green dots are drawn manually on that image.

below is the code which runs application.

it searches for images in sd card with hard coded name and extention. it gets all the ibages but i am unable to understand wha it does with those images because it shows only one image on screen.

also dont know test.txt is created. this code is present in library as AndroidMagickActivity

i did some changes in android.mk file after searching for long time and now its running but the output is not that good.

please anybody help me to improve results of lilac library or help me to understand how to use https://github.com/puelocesar/android-lib-magick

i am beginner and i don't know how to use NDK and how to create JNI and .so files

```
package magick;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.os.Message;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.magick.R;
import magick.util.DisplayImageMetaData;
import magick.util.MagickBitmap;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.*;

public class AndroidMagickActivity extends Activity {
    static final int PROGRESS_DIALOG = 0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.app_notes);


        try {
            final MagickImage img = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo("/sdcard/1.jpg"));

            /*
             * ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
             * iv.setImageBitmap(MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(img));
             * setContentView(iv);
             */
//          setContentView(R.layout.main);
            Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
            ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.effects, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            s.setAdapter(adapter);

            s.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int pos, long id) {
                    ProgressThread t = new ProgressThread(img, pos);
                    //runOnUiThread(t);
                    t.run();
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                    // Do nothing.
                }
            });
            ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            iv.setImageBitmap(MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(img));
        } catch (MagickApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MagickException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * TextView tv = new TextView(this);
         * tv.setText(DisplayImageMetaData.displayMagickImage(img));
         * setContentView(tv);
         */
        int count = 2;
        MagickImage images[] = new MagickImage[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String path = "/sdcard/" + String.valueOf(i + 1) + ".jpg";
            try {
                images[i] = new MagickImage(new ImageInfo(path));
            } catch (MagickException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            MagickImage image = new MagickImage(images);
            image.setImageFormat("gif");
            String fn = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Pictures/test.gif";
            image.setFileName(fn);
            ImageInfo info = new ImageInfo(fn);
            info.setMagick("gif");
            //image.writeImage(info);
            byte blob[] = image.imageToBlob(info);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fn);
            fos.write(blob);
            fos.close();
            FileOutputStream testOS = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/test.txt");
            testOS.write("abc".getBytes());
            testOS.close();
        } catch (MagickException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Bundle bundle) {
        switch (id) {
        case PROGRESS_DIALOG:
            /*
             * ProgressDialog dialog =
             * ProgressDialog.show(AndroidMagickActivity.this, "",
             * "Loading. Please wait...", true);
             */
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidMagickActivity.this);
            progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            return progressDialog;
            // return dialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }


    /** Nested class that performs progress calculations (counting) */
    private class ProgressThread extends Thread {

        MagickImage img;
        int pos;

        ProgressThread(MagickImage image, int pos) {
            this.img = image;
            this.pos = pos;
        }

        public void run() {
            int effect = 0;
            AndroidMagickActivity.this.showDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            switch (pos) {
            case 1:
                effect = NoiseType.UndefinedNoise;
                break;
            case 2:
                effect = NoiseType.UniformNoise;
                break;
            case 3:
                effect = NoiseType.GaussianNoise;
                break;
            case 4:
                effect = NoiseType.MultiplicativeGaussianNoise;
                break;
            case 5:
                effect = NoiseType.ImpulseNoise;
                break;
            case 6:
                effect = NoiseType.LaplacianNoise;
                break;
            case 7:
                effect = NoiseType.PoissonNoise;
                break;
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

                MagickImage image = null;
                if (pos < 8)
                    image = img.addNoiseImage(effect);
                else if (pos == 9)
                    image = img.blurImage(5, 1);
                else if (pos == 10)
                    image = img.charcoalImage(5, 1);
                else if (pos == 11)
                    image = img.edgeImage(0);
                if (image != null) {

                    bitmap = MagickBitmap.ToBitmap(image);
                    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
                // bitmap.recycle(); we can't do that.
                AndroidMagickActivity.this.dismissDialog(PROGRESS_DIALOG);
            } catch (MagickException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can we see what you have so far? Edit it into your question.

Comment: as i said i downloaded this https://github.com/lilac/Android-ImageMagick researched alot make it work.... now its working but effects it gives are not satisfactory.... as i dont have reputaion i cant post images... and i dont understand what code to post here because used the library and made changes to run it properly...

Comment: OK, post something on an external image website (say, Tinypic). Also, let's see code - you clearly have some of that, so let's see that too. What in particular is unsatisfactory about your present results? You haven't yet said. (It is better to edit the question to improve it, rather than to add substantial extra detail in the comments, btw).

Comment: @halfer i did as you suggested... please have a look at it and tell me what more i should do. thank you.

Comment: Not for me to answer - I'm not an Android dev. But your question now is a bit better. I'd recommend labelling the two hyperlinks that illustrate the library not working for you - at the moment you're expecting people to load up 9 images, which is a bit of a hassle!

Comment: @halfer please refer this question to some you know and can answer it

Comment: @Siddhesh....please let me know how you made it work?? I am not able to make imagemagick work....

Comment: @SreekanthKarumanaghat actually i don't remember what changes i made but i can tell you that i made changes about path in some .mk and .so files if you are using imagemagick library and if you are using library mentioned above i think i haven't made any changes in it just added an image in emulator's sd card. image magick didn't gave me result i wanted because i think it needs to work with ndk. i have not completed this thing yet.

Comment: @Siddhesh..The thing is that I want to handle large images..I think I can achieve this if I get imagemagick to work...any help in this subject will be highly appreciated...Can you share your working project with me if you don't mind....I have been spending more than 4 days in this topic...

Comment: sorry i cant since code is not mine

Comment: I have downloaded the code from github...all I want is to make it work....I dont want any modifications or your piece of code...I just need a working piece of project....

Comment: I've ported it here, works https://github.com/tapaulo/Android-ImageMagick